# CodeIgniter Active Record - return a non-associative array as result

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

Is there a way to return a non-associative array as a result of a CI db query?
Say, I have this table:

```
id | Name
 1 | Name1
 2 | Name2
 3 | Name3
 4 | Name4
```

I want the names to be returned as a non-associative array.

`$this->db->select('tablename')->result_array()` returns an associative array.

Is this even possible in CI? I don't want to have to add an extra `foreach` statement if it is.

Please shed some light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use [array_values()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php), which returns an array containing the values of your associative array.

Comment: I'll try that one when I get the chance. Unfortunately, I'm working on something else now.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built in function for this (or at least i have never seen any), I would suggest using another function for this using your `foreach` loop method.

There may be other ways I would suggest looking on the CI forums, im sure some else has had this problem before.

Sorry i can't be anymore help.